# Magento can't register new customer + customer can't change password after upgrade to 1.9.3.1

Tags: upgrade, customer-account, change-password

I've upgraded from Magento CE 1.6.2.0 to CE 1.9.3.1, but did so with the following command: `ditto -V path/to/magento/1.9.3.1/ path/to/magento/1.6.2.0`.

After putting this live, there was an error when going to **System -> Configuration** (blank page), as described in [this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce18-ee113/ce1.8_release-notes.html#11810-changes-upgrade-issue) article section. So after reading this I found out there were a lot more files that didn't get deleted, so I deleted and replaced the **src/code/core** and **src/lib** directories to be on par with the actual upgraded version.

Everything so far works as expected, but now I can't create a customer, or change the password for an existing customer (both from customer account as in backend). It fails somewhere with handling the password. I've been able to trace it back to the **createPostAction** and **editPostAction** within **src/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php**, but I'm stuck there.

Has anyone come across this before and how can I fix this? Many thanks to whoever can help me.

**Note**: I now this is not the normal way of handling upgrades, but this was the only way availeble for me (Magento Connect is disabled). I've also checked the template file, as described [here](https://community.magento.com/t5/Technical-Issues/Customer-Registration-not-working-in-1-9-2-2/td-p/20563)

Comment: When you inspect the customer form, can you see a div that contains a form_key? It should be just after the opening form tag.

Comment: The form key is in the proper place in all of the register.phtml files, the problem persists when the default template is used instead of my own.

Answer (score 0):

Do Following Changes

1. copy all file and folder of 1.9.3.1 and paste it into your site
2. regarding your 1st issue System -> Configuration (blank page) go to app\code\core\Mage\GoogleCheckout\etc and delete system.xml and adminhtml.xml
3. and your 2nd issue is of form key issue so put form key into your login and registration form

Comment: After I looked at that solution, I completely removed the app/code/core folder and replaced it with the new one, which doesn't contain those files. This was an issue, but in fixing it, I came across the real problem: the customer registration/password change. (I can still log in existing users and the admin password change still works, but I can't change password for a customer from admin)

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause: I've been working across several branches, with the same database, but in one branch I've updated a specific module (`AheadWorks Points & Rewards`) and they listen on the `customerSaveAfter` to do some checks, but the database is updated to handle the newer version, but the branch I'm currently working on uses the older version, and somewhere this causes an issue.

When I disabled the module and everything works fine. I just needed to update the module on this branch (or merge, even better) to get them to work together.